# what's the correct way to organize tests for this TDD-way code?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

e.g. a [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-pattern/) question has these tests or examples:

```
Input: pattern = "abba", str = "dog cat cat dog"
Output: true
Example 2:

Input:pattern = "abba", str = "dog cat cat fish"
Output: false
Example 3:

Input: pattern = "aaaa", str = "dog cat cat dog"
Output: false
Example 4:

Input: pattern = "abba", str = "dog dog dog dog"
Output: false
```

I wrote function f and now need to test it using examples above:

```
pattern = "abba"
s = "dog dog dog dog"

pattern = "abba"
s = "dog cat cat dog"

pattern = "abba"
s = "dog cat cat fish"

pattern = "aaaa"
s = "dog cat cat dog"

pattern = "abba"
s = "dog dog dog dog"
```

I could simply write assert statements:

```
assert( f(pattern,s)) == False
```

But what's the other 'correct way to write tests using Test-driven development methodology?

Answer (score 0):

> using Test-driven development methodology

A "by the book" approach would look something like

1. Create a checklist, and add a small handful of test ideas to it.  The list doesn't have to be particularly long -- four is enough -- and you can keep adding ideas as you think of them.
2. Pick *one* of the "small" tests to start with
3. Implement that test

3a) Add the production code you need to get the test to compile
3b) Add the production code you need to get the "right" wrong answer

4. Implement just enough code to pass the test; usually you are optimizing for wall clock time here, so often this just means hard coding the right answer.
5. "Refactor" the production code - which is to say, cycle between making small improvements and rerunning the test until you are happy with the quality of the code supporting just this one test.
6. Choose your next test, and repeat steps 3-6 until all of the items on your checklist are done.

```
assert( f("abba","dog cat cat fish")) == False
```

Yup - that's fine.  Depending on local conventions, you might prefer

```
assert ! f("abba","dog cat cat fish")
```

Tests, like production code, benefit from design, so you'll want to consider what characteristics (beyond telling the machine what to do) you want the test code to have.